# Scala: Difference between #::: and ++ with LazyLists

Tags: scala, concatenation, lazy-evaluation

I would expect #::: and ++ to behave identically when both operands are LazyLists.  Indeed, with the following code typed into a VS Code / Metals worksheet:

```
LazyList.from(0) ++ LazyList.from(0)
LazyList.from(0) #::: LazyList.from(0)
```

both evaluate to `LazyList[Int] = LazyList(<not computed>)`.  Makes perfect sense.  And if I do this:

```
def countFrom(initial: LazyList[Int]): LazyList[Int] =
    LazyList(initial.head) #::: countFrom(LazyList(initial.head + 1))

val m1 = countFrom(LazyList(0))
```

VS Code shows that m1 evaluates to: `LazyList[Int] = LazyList(<not computed>)` which again makes perfect sense to me.  No one asked for any elements, so nothing should be computed yet.  But if I change the #::: to ++ as per the following:

```
def countFrom(initial: LazyList[Int]): LazyList[Int] =
    LazyList(initial.head) ++ countFrom(LazyList(initial.head + 1))

val m1 = countFrom(LazyList(0))
```

then VS Code cannot evaluate m1 due to a stack overflow error while evaluating countFrom calling countFrom calling countFrom, etc.  (Btw, yes, this is bizarre, contrived code.  It's a simplification of code from a project I was working on that was constructing more interesting LazyLists.)

So apparently there IS a difference between ++ and #::: which is not exposed when concatenating LazyLists generated via the built-in from method, but which IS exposed by my (weird) countFrom method.  Can anyone explain what's going on here?

*[added after Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's comment]*

Thanks to Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I think I get it now, so I'm going to try to explain the details after having looked at the LazyList source (feel free to fix me if I get something wrong!).  In the expression `X #::: Y`, `Y` is `this`, and `X` is the argument (which is why the parameter to `#:::` is named `prefix` in the scala docs).  Since `#:::` is defined on `Deferrer`, this causes an implicit conversion of `Y` (a LazyList) into a `Deferrer`, which wraps `Y` into a thunk (nullary function).  `X #::: Y` then becomes `X lazyAppendedAll toDeferrer(Y)()`.  Then, I guess the key is that the second parameter to `lazyAppendedAll` is pass-by-name, so `toDeferrer(Y)()` is not actually evaluated until it is needed.  Now as for `++`, I did not see a definition of ++ in the LazyList source, so I guess it gets inherited and has a much simpler definition where, with `X ++ Y`, `X` is `this` and `Y` is the argument and `Y` is passed by value, and is thus evaluated on entry to `++`.  Since `Y` is a `LazyList`, the elements are not calculated, but `Y` must be evaluated down to the `LazyList` itself, and that's where the infinite recursion results.

Comment: `#:::` is lazy on the tail, whereas`++` is not. So the later has to evaluate the tail _(not its elements)_ and since it is a recursive definition it crashes.

Comment: Thanks!  By "tail", did you actually mean "second operand"?  (Since both ++ and #::: concatenate entire lists together, as opposed to cons'ing a head onto a tail.)  I think I get it now!

Comment: Well the second operator is still the tail. Anyways, that is also a conceptual difference. `++` is concatenation whereas is `#:::` is prepend many.